# Neo4j match multiple relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How can I write a query that gets nodes that have relationships to ALL nodes of a set. For example:

```
START n=node:people("username:*"), 
g=node:groups("groupname:A groupname:B") 
MATCH n-[:M]->g 
RETURN n
```

This returns users that have relationships to A *or* B. But I want users that have relationships to A *and* B. I can't figure out how to do it though.

Edit:

I need to do this for an arbitrary number of groups, not just A and B. And the reason I'm using index syntax is that this is from user input, so it could be this:

```
START n=node:people("username:*"), 
g=node:groups("groupname:*") 
MATCH n-[:M]->g 
RETURN n
```

And I would need to return users that have the M relationship with ALL groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
START n=node:people("username:*"), 
g=node:groups("groupname:*") 
with n, collect(g) as groups
MATCH n-[:M]->ug
with n, collect(ug) as user_groups
where ALL(g in groups WHERE g in user_groups)
RETURN n
```

it might even work like this (should be faster)

```
START n=node:people("username:*"), 
g=node:groups("groupname:*") 
with n, collect(g) as groups
MATCH n-[:M]->ug
WHERE ug in groups
with n, count(*) as found, length(groups) as group_count
WHERE found = group_count
RETURN n
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate groups A and B into distinct variables and then ensure each match exists individually.

```
START n=node:people("username:*"), 
gA=node:groups("groupname:A"),
gB=node:groups("groupname:B") 
MATCH n-[:M]->gA, n-[:M]->gB 
RETURN n
```

Comment: So the problem is I need to be able to support an arbitrary number of groups.